# retrieving data from two tables based on a condition

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables TABLE users and TABLE assign_project. I need to get those user id that are not in assign_project table based on the role_id.

The fields in users table:

```
 - user_id
 - username
 - role_id
 - company_id
```

The fields in the assign_project table:

```
  - id
  - project_id
  - user_id
```

The code is

```
    $company_id = 1;

    //get the project details of the project $project_id
    $projects = Project::where('project_id','=',$project_id)->get();

    //get the company id of the project $project_id
    $company_id = Project::where('project_id','=',$project_id)->value('company_id');

    //get the users whom the $project_id is assigned
    $users = DB::table('assign_project')
            ->where('project_id','=', $project_id)
            ->get();

    // if $project_id is assigned to any user retrieve only those
    //with role id = 2 and with the company id $company_id
    //whom $project_id is not assigned

    foreach ($users as $row) {
        $designation = User::where('user_id','<>',$row->assigned_to)
                    ->where('role_id','=',2)
                    ->where('company_id','=',$company_id)
                    ->get();
    }
```

I am not getting the output.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? No output? I am not aware of the APIs you are using, ... just a hunch ... isn't it possible for you to just write one query to select those users who are not there in projects?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I can't see any user<->company relation

Comment: @jaysingkar Sorry I forgot to add company_id in the users table. But it is present in the database already still it is not working.

Comment: Thanks to all. I have fixed the issue. It was a mistake on model. Thanks again.